# App Delegate issue, MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have just started using MonoTouch and iPhone SDK. But I have en problem, where I want to create an tableView, but all examples i have found are binding the App Delegate Object to the view, but then I create me example, the App Delegate is an class inside MonoDevelop. And the problem is that I can't access the TableView controller in the appDelegate.cs file.

How do I bridge that problem? I wonder if the problem is that the example I'm using is made in xCode 3 and im using the lates xCode 4 and it is doing things another way.

Are there any guides for monotouch there shows me have to do it in XCode4. Because thats the only problem I have right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seperate your data from your views by using a programming model like MVC, this should solve the problem.

Accessing the TableView from the AppDelegate is not a good idea.

Comment: But where is there an guide to me in the right direction. Because as i said im new to monotouch. I have ben using this guide which says i had to do it http://www.infoq.com/articles/monotouch-custom-tables

Answer (score 1):

Start with the MonoTouch [tutorials](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/getting_started). They'll explain you on how to use XCode4 and MonoDevelop together. After that it will be much easier to learn / re-use existing samples (e.g. that depends on Xcode 3).

If you're looking at tables you might want to check [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) (but after the turorials ;-). The API is much easier to learn and it comes with a great sample application.